# display data as links in webgrid

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, webmatrix, webgrid

I would like to display data read from the database as links, each of which will call a js function when clicked.

The data read are inserted into a webgrid and displayed on the browser like this

```
    <div>
        @grid.GetHtml(               
            columns:grid.Columns(
                grid.Column("Country"),
                grid.Column("Capital")              
            )
        )
    </div>
```

That simply does the output but only the table heads are turned into links by default.

I have tried this

```
         columns:grid.Columns(
                grid.Column(columnName:"Country",header:"Country",format:@<a href="#" onclick="Find();return false;"></a>),
                grid.Column("Capital")              
            )
```

But this deletes all the countries and replaces them with "" (empty string) and that is also not what I would like to do.

I would like to make the data output as links that can be clicked to execute "Find" js function. I don't know how to format the table data not the table heads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text for a link appears between the opening  and closing  tags. You currently have nothing there. Alter it as follows to have the Country appear:

```
format:@<a href="#" onclick="Find();return false;">@item.Country</a>
```